# Google direction API Re-routing issue in Android

Tags: routes, directions

I am building a navigation based application for android using google directions API.

In this application I am drawing a route from points selected by the user. I have issues of recalculating route if user is not following the route.

For Calculating the route I have used Google direction API. While calculating the re-route, it is always returning the previous route from the current position.

By the way, Google navigator APP calculates from current position to destination based on car direction. How can I make similar suggestion?

Below is the HTTP Request I used in the code to get the directions.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.432989,78.408225&destination=17.427455,78.41431300000001&sensor=false

Can any one tell me the solution from which I can get the directions json based on car direction.

Thanks in advance,
Ramesh.P